# My Website is stuck on pre-loader loop (CSS broken)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Newbie here, and first time experiencing this issue. My website ([www.kandomedia.co.za](http://www.kandomedia.co.za)) works perfectly fine when i was developing it offline on my local machine as per attached image.
[Kando Media Website Local Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97hbZ.jpg)

But as soon as i upload it to my hosting account, its stuck on the preloader screen (if you visit [www.kandomedia.co.za/new/](http://www.kandomedia.co.za/new/) you can see this in action)

I have done quite a bit of research on google to try resolve this issue, but still cannot fix it. If i take away the preloader completely, the website is not formatted correctly like it looks on my local machine. It seems the site is not loading the CSS files etc.

I have checked, double checked and triple checked to make sure all the paths are correct, and that everything is where it is supposed to be. But still no luck.

This is the structure in the head tag:

```html
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- ===============================================-->
    <!--    Document Title-->
    <!-- ===============================================-->
    <title>Kando Media (Pty) Ltd :: Website design, graphic design and website hosting services South Africa</title>

    <!-- ===============================================-->
    <!--    Favicons-->
    <!-- ===============================================-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="manifest" href="assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="assets/img/favicons/mstile-150x150.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <!-- ===============================================-->
    <!--    Stylesheets-->
    <!-- ===============================================-->
    <link href="assets/lib/loaders.css/loaders.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/lib/remodal/remodal.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/lib/remodal/remodal-default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/lib/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/lib/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/lib/semantic-ui-accordion/accordion.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/lib/semantic-ui-transition/transition.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet"  href="assets/css/theme.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
```

Where am i going wrong here? I havent slept a whole day trying to figure this out. Even my friend who is an experienced developer cant figure it out (unless he doesnt want to help me haha)

Please help, id really appreciate it.

Comment: It's quite hard to debug your code if everything is minified. The only error visible in the console is "data is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be an error with some data on theme.js

here is what i found on you site with f12 dev tools on crhome:

[image]

can you check this out first? :)

Comment: I have removed some code from theme.js. Going to upload it shortly with what i removed and let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: ok, gonna be here waiting if you need more help! :)